Find all holomorphic, bijective maps $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0 \} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$
I am trying to characterize all holomorphic maps $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0 \} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ which are bijective.
I think you can say from Picard’s Great Theorem that the singularity at the origin cannot be essential, otherwise the function would not be one-to-one, so it is either a removable singularity or a pole. But I wasn’t sure how to progress from there to fully characterize these functions.

Hint: Such a map must be a biholomorphism. What can you say about biholomorphisms and simply-connectedness? (Assuming that by one-to-one you mean "bijective").

@BenSteffan I believe you are correct, the question only really makes sense if f is onto as well. I updated the question to say f is bijective.

There are no such maps.
As I hinted in the comments, any such map must be a biholomorphism (because any injective holomorphic function is a biholomorphism onto its image), in particular a homeomorphism; but $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are not homeomorphic to each other: The latter is simply-connected, the former isn't.
